# Could you lose your data if something goes wrong when you upgrade your OS to version 16?

Tags: upgrade

I also would like to know a few other things. I need to know roughly the size that would be downloaded (roughly). Would it be in GB's, or in hundreds of MB's or anything else that I need to know. Can I work on my system while the files are being downloaded? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always lose data if something goes wrong, but it's not that likely. Even if the upgrade messes up, you can use the Live Environment to copy files to a USB drive and reinstall.

The upgrade will tell you exactly how much it is going to download when you start it. You can cancel it then if it's too much. The size varies per user, as everyone has a slightly different setup, but a near-fresh install of 15.10 with all packages fully updated says the upgrade will download 789MB. This is probably different on 14.04, and is a very low estimate, since there are only the default packages installed. The Ubuntu 16.04 ISO itself is around 1.4GB, but that's not accurate for an upgrade.

You can use Ubuntu throughout the whole upgrade process, but that's not necessarily a good idea. It's perfectly fine to keep using your computer while the upgrade downloads, but keep an eye on it and stop doing stuff when it actually begins upgrading.

Comment: Does upgrading to 16 provide me any benefit in terms of performance?

Comment: From looking at the questions flowing in on Ask Ubuntu recently, the upgrade paths to 16.04 seem not that solid yet, so I strongly suggest making a full backup before starting the upgrade. And about performance... A fresh reinstall of the new release, overwriting the old installation (after backing up all the data so that you can copy it back afterwards) will always result in the best performance you can get. Upgraded systems *may* become slower, but this varies very much from system to system and depends on many factors.

Comment: I downloaded the ISO and tried to install it, and there are three options it provides me: 1. To create a separate partition if I need to retain all the data in it. 2. To erase disk completely and install, 3. The data of ubuntu 14.04 would be removed and 16 would be installed. I need to retain all the data and install 16 instead of 14, not create a separate partition for it. So How do I go about it? What does the third option mean when he said files related to 14.04 would be lost? Thank you.

Comment: if you're keeping your data and installing 16.04 without creating a new partition, you're upgrading. Check ou thte guides on putting /home on a separate partition and go from there.